# Are the gradients obtained by tf.gradients() or optimizer.compute_gradients() negated already?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

Are the gradients obtained by tf.gradients() or optimizer.compute_gradients() negated already?

For example, for gradient descent, we know that the direction should be set to negetive gradient, -E'(W), where E'(W) is the gradient, E(W) is the loss.

And, in Tensorflow, through tf.gradients() or tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer.compute_gradients(), we can obtain the gradients. But are the obtained gradients set to negetive already?

If we would like to do some calculations on the gradients, I think it will be important for us to know if gradients have been negated or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, the gradients are not negated, they follow the proper gradient definition. Here's a TF 2.0 example (using gradient tape):

```
x = tf.constant(2.)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(x)
    y = x**2
print(tape.gradient(y, x))
```

This will print `tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)`, (i.e. 2*x) which we can see is not negated.

In TF 1.X, `tf.gradients` gives the same result. `optimizer.compute_gradients` simply uses that function, so once again it will give the same result.

Negation needs to be handled by the user, i.e. if you want to implement gradient descent yourself you will need to *subtract* the gradients from the variables in order to minimize the loss. In the `Optimizer` classes, this is included in the `apply_gradients` step (i.e. here, the *negative* gradients are applied).

Comment: Thank you so much. really appreciate it.